# Visual Studio Sidebar Navigation

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-extensions

I am looking for free extension that has one simple functionality which is sidebar file navigation like is in SuperCharger or Resharper (see attached screenshots). Sadly both of them are paid :-(  Does anyone have a good alternative?

[image: Supercharger navigation]
[image: Resharper file structure]

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio has **Class View** window for a quite a while.

[image]

Comment: Sadly this is not usable as it is for whole solution (which in my case has 20+ smaller projects) and not for the currently opened file. Also #region support is well appreciated in mentioned extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Productivity Power Tools, with it, you can:

1. Expand code files to navigate to its classes, expand classes to navigate to their members, and so on (C# and VB only)
2. Search your solution, all the way down to class members
3. Filter your solution or projects to see just opened files, unsaved files, and so on
4. View related information about classes and members (such as references or callers/callees for C#)
5. Preview images by hovering over them, or preview rich information by hovering over code items
6. We've also added support for multiple selection and drag & drop.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ProductivityPowerTools

Comment: This is not the desired solution as it is not that simple as just navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, but as i was looking for an alternative to supercharger // Resharper (for the navigation only) few days ago, and had looked on stack before doing my search (and as I found the answers not exactly what i was looking for) ...

After testing a few extensions I finally found a good alternative to those two paid solutions :

https://github.com/sboulema/CodeNav/blob/master/README.md

You can also just download it from the extensions menu , search for CodeNav .

Best.